# Why does clang ignore inline threshold flag?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-flags

I'm trying to find ways to compile my project optimally, however I've noted that if I pass `-Rpass-missed=inline -mllvm -inline-threshold=500` I get nonsense output like the following:

```
src/getargv.c:241:5: remark: errorB not inlined into get_argv_of_pid because too costly to inline (cost=0, threshold=0) [-Rpass-missed=inline]
    errorB(procargs);
    ^
src/getargv.c:21:14: remark: parseInt not inlined into main because too costly to inline (cost=285, threshold=225) [-Rpass-missed=inline]
      skip = parseInt(optarg);
```

Clearly the threshold I specified is neither 0 nor 225, so why is clang either ignoring or not understanding the flags I set?

Comment: You might have an answer here https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-May/099805.html *-mllvm -inline-threshold no longer honored?*

Comment: Huh, fixed 5 years ago, still not released. I can't pretend to understand how the llvm project plans releases but that seems insane.

Comment: that's why I use gcc ;) Note that you can have a quick (dirty?) fix by inlining yourself (removing some function calls and copy/paste the code block). It could be a solution

Comment: Yeah, but I'm ok with waiting for llvm/clang 13. Manual inlining would make testing my code much harder.

Comment: Since it is a regression you could use llvm/clang 3.8.0 release. (where it was still working), and benchmark to see if its working a bit better.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL you should post that link along with a brief explanation/quote as an answer.